Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Особенно интересует запятая перед первым "что"
Для неё теперь, что день, что ночь - темнота.

Правильно:
Для неё теперь, что день, что ночь — темнота.
Сравнить: Для неё теперь, как день, так и ночь — темнота.
Пояснение:
Это БСП, две предикативные основы: (1) Для неё теперь — предложение эллиптического вида (без сказуемого); (2) что день, что ночь — темнота.
Отношения изъяснительные (вмещающего типа): Для нее теперь // (что?). Обозначены запятой. Во второй части однородные подлежащие что день, что ночь.
Это фразеологическая конструкция, характерная для разговорной речи.
